# How to determine which column user clicked on ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a datagridview in asp.net using c#. I am using this code to make the row selectable:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvTasks, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
    }
}

protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTasks.Rows)
   {
       if (row.RowIndex == gvTasks.SelectedIndex)
       {
           DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
           mydt = (DataTable) Session["dt"];

           Response.Redirect("EditTask.aspx?taskID=" + mydt.Rows[gvTasks.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString()
                    + "&agentID=" + mydt.Rows[gvTasks.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString());
       }
       else
       {

       }
    }
}
```

My challenge is that I have added a new databound column which is a link I need the user to navigate to. Since clicking on the row will automatically take you to a certain page (Edit Task in this case), it ends up taking you to the Edit Task page wether I click on the link or any where on the row.

I need to determine which column was clicked on so I can add extra logic that if its a specific column use one url or all others, use another url. I have not found a selectedColumn property on the asp.net datagridview.  What is the best way to determine which column was selected.

Answer (score 3):

`GridView` doesn't have a built-in mechanism that allows to select a column, it won't be possible to only use `GridView` feature.

One way to do it is to set the column number in a hidden field when the user click on a field and then retrieve this hidden field value inside the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.

Outside of the gridview, insert a new hiddenField

```
<asp:hiddenField runat="server" id="hfColumnId" />
```

When you click on a row, set this value using JavaScript :

```
$('table#XXX td').click(function(){
    var columnId = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    $('#hfColumnId').val(columnId);
});
```

Then in your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, you can retrieve the columnId using

```
Int32 columnId = Int32.Parse(this.hfColumnId.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first ever answer on Stack overflow: Maybe what you need to do is to use a slightly different approach. Since your objective is to have the user go to a link they click from the datagrid you should instead create a column at runtime that will have that link. You can do it in 2 ways, Programmatically or asp. Will answer Programmatically

1. Programmatically: This code starts at the time you bind your grid

   GridView1.DataBind(); //After you have bound your grid view do the following

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {

           HyperLink hlContro = new HyperLink();
           hlContro.NavigateUrl = "./newPage.aspx?ID=" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text; //This is where your url is being kept in the grid
        hlContro.Text = "Click me to go to the link";
          GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls.Add(hlContro);//adds the control to the gridview

       }
   ```

Many thanks to people who helped me on stack overflow and got me to where I can help you too today. hope I helped. - Samcima